# How to disable the virtual key pad in Android?

Tags: android, screen, virtual-keyboard

I would like to disable the virtual key pad that appears when the focus falls on a edit text element.

I've tried it with the following code:

```
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditTextYears)).setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

This works partially. The virtual key pad doesn't appear, but I can't focus on the edit text element as well, which I need to be able to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably this should help
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-hide-virtual-keyboard-through-code/